# Java Collections Map to Set

Tags: java, api, collections

I am wanting to convert a HashMap to a Set.I am trying to find common elements between two maps by first putting that to a set and use retainAll.How to convert a Map to a Set.

Comment: Well do you want the keys or the values? The two collection types are fundamentally different...

Comment: what are you trying to put into the set? the keys? values? or key value pair? All 3 are accessable via the Map api

Comment: @Internet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29

Comment: I actually want key-value pairs

Comment: @Internet, so what have you tried?  Show us some code and we can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a set containing the keys use:

```
Set<KEY_TYPE> set = map.keySet();
```

If you want a set containing the values use:

```
Set<VALUE_TYPE> set = new HashSet<VALUE_TYPE>(map.values());
```

if you want a set containing both elements use:

```
Set<Map.Entry<KEY_TYPE, VALUE_TYPE>> set = map.entrySet();
```

You access the elements of an `Entry` using `getKey()` and `getValue()`

Answer (score 1):

HashMap has a key set and a value set, to keep the associativity, HashMap has a method called

```
entrySet()
```

you can find more info about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the comments, you want key-value pairs. This you can easily get from the map. Here is an example:

```
Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
// ... put values into your map

Set<Entry<Integer, String>> entrySet = myMap.entrySet();
```

Although from your question I'm not sure this is all you want. Maybe you should rephrase your question and post your code what you did so far, so that we can understand where exactly you need help.